# Splitting one Div into two css sections?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I would like some help in getting my css working.

Now what I would like to do is make a shadow appear on a div when the user starts to scroll.

At the moment I have.

**HTML**

```
<div class="head shadow"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .head {
    background: #edeff0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70px;
    top: 0;
    left: 85px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.shadow {
    display:none;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
     $(document).scroll(function () {
     var y = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (y > 1) {
         $('.shadow').fadeIn();
     } else {
         $('.shadow').fadeOut();
     }

 });
```

Now if I remove 
    display:none;
everything will show, and if I put it back it will hide everything.

How can I get it to only hide the shadows and make the javascript work.

[Here is a working (well it's not working) version](http://jsfiddle.net/aled2305/pBYgs/)

Thanks

Aled

Comment: Just use toggleClass() or if you want to use seperate function, use addClass() and removeClass()

Comment: what I would like to do is use the css to hide the shadows so that the script can then shoe them again on scroll?

Comment: My answer below outlines what you need to do. It adds or removes the shadow class depending on what's happened. You need to get rid of display: none;

Comment: I'd like to see any of the answers actually explaining what the problem is and why their solution fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WORKING FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/yY4U8/

HTML:

```
<div class="head"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 1) {
        $('.head').addClass('shadow');
    } else {
        $('.head').removeClass('shadow');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.shadow {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

The above solution adds the `class` of `shadow` to the element with the class of `head` if the scroll is true, else it will remove it. The reason you were having issues before is because you were using `display: none;` which will completely hide the entire element, not JUST the styling for that class

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aled2305/pBYgs/12/ i've updated the code, but it still don't work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/yY4U8/ - here is a working fiddle. Everything works as it should

Comment: Thanks Andy, just one more thing, is there any way of getting the shadow to fade in and out?

Comment: You'll probably have to do that with some css magic. Transition of opacity etc. I've added an explanation as to why my solution works for you, if it has helped, please upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/pBYgs/10/)**

(Please do not forget to include jquery)

**HTML**

```
<div class="head"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.head {
    background: #edeff0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70px;
    top: 0;
    left: 85px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.shadow {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
     var y = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (y > 1) {
         $('.head').addClass("shadow");
     } else {
        $('.head').removeClass("shadow");
     }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.shadow {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;

  -webkit-transition-property: all
  -moz-transition-property: all
  -ms-transition-property: all
  -o-transition-property: all
  transition-property: all

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.shadow.scrolled {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

$(document).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
     $('.shadow').addClass("scrolled");
  } else {
     $('.shadow').removeClass("scrolled");
  }
});
```

Comment: by the way *don't* use vendor prefixes...
use a precompiler.sass and compass for example.
Or less

Comment: Watch out when using toggleClass() on events that launch rapidly such as scroll.
You want to have exact control of whats happening.
toggleClass() is good to use but can lead to inconsistency.